# Does react native have a stable version (asking since the version starts with zero)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

A flutter developer criticized react native saying that it does not have a stable version since the latest version number starts with 0.x.x which marks an unstable version.

However, react native documentation states [here](https://archive.reactnative.dev/versions) that all version since 0.5 are stable.

So I wanna know which one is true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Version_1.0_as_a_milestone), and I think that most people will agree with it, the flutter guy is right...

I tried to find out why there is still no react native 1.x version but failed. It is strange indeed.

The reality, however, is that a package version number can start with 0 and the package is much more stable than another package with version number starting with a higher number.

I believe that when somebody goes from 0.x to 1.x she usually doesn't mean to say 'there are no bugs' but that she believes that it has reasonable quality, that it is stable and she believes that it does its job well.

**Having said all of this, I feel confident to use react native in production, and millions of others seem to feel the same.**

Comment: The [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/#spec-item-4) standard states this as well

Comment: When React Native was initially released at that time they did not follow semver. And suddenly they cannot use semver that is the reason they are following the normal version flow once v1 is release they will start following semver.

Comment: "she usually doesn't mean to say 'there are no bugs'." Of course not, she knows the lesson of IEFBR14.

Answer (score 1):

When React Native was released for open source they did not follow the semantic version.

This is the official blog post where they planned for new architecture, semantic versioning, & more improved features.

https://reactnative.dev/blog/2018/11/01/oss-roadmap

If you look closely at the release versions, the version before the blog post is v0.56 & after the post it is v0.59. There were a lot of changes to support AndroidX, cocoa pods as default & react hooks.

https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059

And the word **stable** is used to represent there will be no breaking changes in the next patch release for the same version.

https://reactnative.dev/versions

---

In the end, I agree that any software that follows a semantic version & have a version below v1 is not a good idea to be used for production.

## My opinion

I have many react native apps on the production level and didn't find any difficulties or issues. So yes I think React native is stable for building cross platform mobile applications.

Many developers or companies complained that React Native is not a good option for mobile application development but I being from a web development background found it more comfortable and easy to use.

Comment: In my opinion, the statement "any software that follows a semantic version & have a version below v1 is not a good idea to be used for production" is wrong in the case of react native.

Comment: They started following semver after v0.56. So it will be maintained properly after the release of the first major version. The same is the case for the expo. And in the past material UI also messed up the versioning.